# Shortest path algorithm using Dijkstra's Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, priority-queue, dijkstra, shortest-path

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from a starting node to the last node of a 250px by 200px raw image file (e.g. starting node = [0][0], ending node = [250][200]). The raw file acts like a topographical map in that each byte represents an elevation and the distance cost from one node to its adjacent node(s) is the difference in elevations of the two nodes plus 1 for the energy to move from one node to its neighbor (movement can only happen horizontally and vertically).

I have followed the pseudocode for the algorithm using a priority queue in C++, but am struggling to debug to see if I have successfully implemented the algorithm correctly as well as implementing the algorithm to accomplish this unique and relatively challenging situation. Also, my goal is to output the shortest path in a raw file and then view it in Photoshop to see if it is being displayed correctly, but have failed completely at this task.

After all that, my question is...

1. Are there any visible/blaring logical errors in my implementation of solving the above described problem?

2. Could anyone suggest some ideas on how to try to output the shortest path in a raw file or something along similar lines?

Thank you for your help.

p.s. I know I've used file read and write operations with the C notation rather than the stream operations of C++ so there's no need of telling me how I can change that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>

#define INFINITY 99999
#define MAP_SIZE 50000  // 250px by 200px


void dijkstra(int, int, unsigned int []);

// The terminology 'Node' and 'Vertex' are used interchangeably
// throughout the program.
struct Node
{
    int index;              // index of node in graph
    unsigned int distance;  // distance from source (only allow positive distances)
};

// A simple class to compare the distances of two Node structures.
class CompareDist
{
public:
    bool operator()(Node& n1, Node& n2)
    {
        if (n1.distance < n2.distance)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};


int main()
{
    FILE *fr = fopen("map.raw","rb");
    FILE *fw1 = fopen("path.raw","w+");

    int i;
    unsigned char read[MAP_SIZE];
    unsigned int original[MAP_SIZE];    //2D array implemented in 1D array
    unsigned char path[MAP_SIZE];


    if(!fr){
        std::cout<<"Error: Can't open raw file!"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fread(read, sizeof(char), MAP_SIZE, fr);
    fclose(fr);

    //convert to int for calculation
    for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) {
        original[i] = (int)((unsigned short)read[i]);
    }


    dijkstra(0, MAP_SIZE, original);


    for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) {
        path[i] = (unsigned char)original[i]; // output path array
    }

    fwrite(&path,sizeof(char),MAP_SIZE,fw1);

    fclose(fw1);


    return 0;
}

// Implementation of dijkstra's algorithm using a priority queue
// Inputs: int s --> source node
//         int size --> the total number of vertices in graph
//         unsigned int graph[] --> your graph
// Outputs: nothing
void dijkstra(int source, int size, unsigned int graph[MAP_SIZE])
{
    bool *visited = new bool [size];                    // array to check which vertices have already been visited
    unsigned int *distance = new unsigned int [size];   // table to hold the distances of each vertex from the source vertex

    // initialize the distance of each node to infinity and visited as false
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        distance[i] = INFINITY;
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    // the distance of the source to itself is obviously 0
    distance[source] = 0;

    // create priority queue structure
    std::priority_queue< Node, std::vector< Node >, CompareDist> priorityQ;

    // Create the first node as the source and put it into the queue
    Node first = { source, 0 };
    priorityQ.push(first);

    // Pick the top node of priority queue.
    // Update the queue with next visited vertex after checking
    // which non-visited vertex has the minimum distance from
    // the source vertex.
    while(!priorityQ.empty())
    {
        Node tempNode = priorityQ.top();
        priorityQ.pop();
        int nodeIndex = tempNode.index;

        visited[nodeIndex] = true;
        for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
        {
            if(graph[i] != 0 && !visited[i])
            {
                // Update the distance if it is smaller than the current distance
                int tempDist = distance[nodeIndex] + graph[i] + 1;
                if(distance[i] > tempDist)
                {
                    distance[i] = tempDist;
                    Node newNode;
                    newNode.index = i;
                    newNode.distance = distance[i];
                    priorityQ.push(newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // DEBUG TEST FOR CORRECT OUTPUT
    std::cout << "The shortest distance from " << source << " to all other nodes is" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " : " << distance[i] << std::endl;
        graph[i] = distance [i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: You're right. This is a better question for codereview. I appreciate the comment.